# Understanding the rules of parsing table construction

Tags: compilers, parsers

I'm studying top-down parsing, especially LL(1) parsing. However, I cannot understand what is the meaning of rules.

[image]

Example grammer is like this

S → ( S ) S | $\epsilon$

How can I derive like below table?

[image]

I read all explanations of textbook, but I cannot totally understand the process of table construction. Are there anyone who can explain more easily about this process?

Comment: If you don't elaborate on what parts you don't understand and where you get stuck either in understanding the definitions or applying them, then isn't there a good chance that you won't understand an explanation given by someone else? This would be a waste of both your time and their time. You can also find many, many other freely available textbooks and other resources that describe this that may better fit what you already know and what works for you. These aren't "easier" explanations but just different perspectives. They have the benefit on not requiring any additional effort to produce.

Comment: Also, if you are going to quote from a textbook, you should properly cite it. This is also beneficial to you as it allows people who have access with that textbook to look up the context. It also benefits others who are using the same textbook.